# How to write map reduce in R?

Tags: r, mapreduce

I am new to R. I know how to write map reduce in Java. I want to try the same in R. So can any one help in giving any samle codes and is there any fixed format there for MapReduce in R.

Please send any link other than this: https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop/wiki/Tutorial

Any sample codes will be more helpful.

Comment: A google search for `[r] mapreduce` will give a number of useful links, like this package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mapReduce/index.html and this blog: http://www.r-bloggers.com/making-sense-of-mapreduce/

Comment: To the person who silently downvoted: This is the summer of love http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/, so I suggest you do one of a few things 1) Explain why the downvote, 2) Explain to the OP how to improve the question 3) Edit the question so it is a good question.

Comment: Not a down-voter but here goes. Manoj, I think you should reword your question a bit. Please add information that you have tried. Something along the lines of "I've been writing MR in Java but now I would like to try it out in R. I've read this tutorial and did this and that search but was interested in more tutorials that have escaped me.". What you could also do is gather a list of all references regarding R and MR (if not already existing) and make this question a wiki.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to implement a map reduce (with Hadoop) in a language other than Java, then you use a feature called streaming. Then the data is fed to the mapper via STDIN (readLines()), back to Hadoop via STDOUT(cat()), then to the reducer again through STDIN (readLines()) and blurted finally via STDOUT (cat()).

The following code is taken from an [article](http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/mapreduce-r-hadoop-amazon-emr/) I wrote on writing a map reduce job with R for Hadoop. The code is supposed to count 2-grams but I'd say simple enough to see what is going on MapReduce-wise.

```
# map.R

library(stringdist, quietly=TRUE)

input <- file("stdin", "r")

while(length(line <- readLines(input, n=1, warn=FALSE)) > 0) {
   # in case of empty lines
   # more sophisticated defensive code makes sense here
   if(nchar(line) == 0) break

   fields <- unlist(strsplit(line, "\t"))

   # extract 2-grams
   d <- qgrams(tolower(fields[4]), q=2)

   for(i in 1:ncol(d)) {
     # language / 2-gram / count
     cat(fields[2], "\t", colnames(d)[i], "\t", d[1,i], "\n")
   }
}

close(input)
```

-

```
# reduce.R

input <- file("stdin", "r")

# initialize variables that keep
# track of the state

is_first_line <- TRUE

while(length(line <- readLines(input, n=1, warn=FALSE)) > 0) {
   line <- unlist(strsplit(line, "\t"))
   # current line belongs to previous
   # line's key pair
   if(!is_first_line &&
      prev_lang == line[1] &&
      prev_2gram == line[2]) {
        sum <- sum + as.integer(line[3])
   }
   # current line belongs either to a
   # new key pair or is first line
   else {
     # new key pair - so output the last
     # key pair's result
     if(!is_first_line) {
       # language / 2-gram / count
       cat(prev_lang,"\t",prev_2gram,"\t",sum,"\n")
     }
     # initialize state trackers
     prev_lang <- line[1]
     prev_2gram <- line[2]
     sum <- as.integer(line[3])
     is_first_line <- FALSE
   }
}

# the final record
cat(prev_lang,"\t",prev_2gram, "\t", sum, "\n")

close(input)
```

---

http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/mapreduce-r-hadoop-amazon-emr/